# MediaCodec is crashed in the configure function during the h265 setting.How to correctly use the mediacodec to decode h265?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, hevc

My code is following：

```
MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/hevc",480, 560);
decoder.configure(format, null, null, 0);
```

My device supports h265 decoding：OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome types:video/hevc

And the crash log：

```
05-09 16:32:16.670: E/xdance(14899): format:{durationUs=0, max-input-size=0, height=560, mime=video/hevc, width=480}
05-09 16:32:16.670: E/ACodec(14899): [OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome] configureCodec returning error -1010
05-09 16:32:16.670: E/MediaCodec(14899): Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001001, internalError -1010)
05-09 16:32:16.670: W/dalvikvm(14899): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41696ba8)
05-09 16:32:16.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14899): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-300
05-09 16:32:16.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14899): Process: com.clientgroup.server, PID: 14899
05-09 16:32:16.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14899): java.lang.IllegalStateException
05-09 16:32:16.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
05-09 16:32:16.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:262)
05-09 16:32:16.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at com.clientgroup.server.SensorServer$PlayerThread.run(SensorServer.java:257)
05-09 16:32:16.680: E/AndroidRuntime(14899):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

So，why the simple use of the mediacodec is not ok. Is anyone can help me?